# How to create powershell script to stop services, delete files, start services

Tags: windows, powershell, service, server

I need to learn / create a script to check files in a folder if they are older than 3 minutes. if they are older, then stop service1, stop service2, delete files older than 3 minutes, start service2, start service1 create output for result and loop the check at 5 minutes (this can be done using task scheduled)

This is my first script and I want to learn scripting so I really appreciate your help. In addition, if you can recommend a good book to learn scripting I will be very happy

Comment: Don't forget to ask your question and include your code.

Comment: The same way you create any other PowerShell script: you launch your preferred editor and start typing. SO is not a place where we teach you the basics of a language. That's what tutorials are for.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go sir ...

[Getting Started with Microsoft PowerShell](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-microsoft-powershell-8276?l=r54IrOWy_2304984382)